# LDAP change password via REST/SOAP

Tags: rest, soap, ldap

I'm trying to change/reset the password of LDAP user via API. But I need to do this throw SOPA/REST 
I didn't find any information regarding this. Maybe someone has such a solution or link to corresponding doc?

Answer (score 0):

LDAP is a protocol and not part of SOAP or REST.

You would need a "Gateway" of some sort. The recent trend would be to use SCIM.

Several LDAP Server implementation provide such services but not within using LDAP.